# Cleaning up repeatable CSS codes

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I got this code working from another thread here. However, I feel like as though I'm not re-using the CSS efficiently. How can I cut/reduce the CSS code further more?

It feels like I'm repeating the keyframes way too much. Also, I'm not sure why loop is used but it doesn't work properly when I remove it.

PS: In the demo, you see only ten, thirty and ninety only. I'll be adding twenty, forty, fifty etc in the actual production code.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dg0L9cw7/1/

```css
#speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#speedometer .barometer {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GAZ.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#speedometer .needle {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GBP.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 999999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  transform-origin: 50% calc(100% - 8px);
}

#speedometer .needle.ten {
  animation: changeTen 3s linear, loopTen 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes changeTen {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loopTen {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
}

#speedometer .needle.thirty {
  animation: changeThirty 3s linear, loopThirty 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes changeThirty {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loopThirty {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
}

#speedometer .needle.ninety {
  animation: changeNinety 3s linear, loopNinety 1s linear 3s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes changeNinety {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(80deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loopNinety {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(80deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(80deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="speedometer">
  <span class="barometer"></span>
  <span class="needle ten"></span>
</div>
<div id="speedometer">
  <span class="barometer"></span>
  <span class="needle thirty"></span>
</div>
<div id="speedometer">
  <span class="barometer"></span>
  <span class="needle ninety"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs can only be used for 1 element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS variables. You can also reduce the markup to only one element:

```css
.speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GAZ.svg");
  width: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.speedometer:before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GBP.svg");
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
  animation: change 3s linear forwards;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
  100% { transform:rotate(var(--r,90deg)); }
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:-60deg;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:-30deg;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--r:80deg;">
</div>
```

You can also make the variable more friendly using some calculation. In the below I am considering percetange so values in the range `[0 100]`

```css
.speedometer {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GAZ.svg");
  width: 200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.speedometer:before {
  content:"";
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/GBP.svg");
  height: 110px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
  animation: change 3s linear forwards;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes change {
  0% { transform:rotate(-90deg); }
  100% { transform:rotate(calc(1.8deg*var(--p) - 90deg)); }
}
```

```html
<div class="speedometer" style="--p:40;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--p:20;">
</div>
<div class="speedometer" style="--p:80;">
</div>
```

Comment: WOW!! Reading up `--p` and *var in css3. This is amazing. btw, would this be supported in most browsers and mobile phones (responsive)?

Comment: @ElaineByene yes the support is pretty good: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables only IE will fail like usual

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new class to include the properties that `.needle` and `.barometer` shares, something like this:

```
.class-name{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

I believe that the `display: inline-block;` in `.needle` and `.barometer` are not necessary as those already are being inherited from `#speedometer` .

using [css variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp) instead of specifically make a property for each transition could make it look much better.

I would also replace `#speedometer` into `.speedometer` because ID should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure CSS (i.e withtout a CSS preprocessor) you can have a `selector` with a class to target elements with similar styling and us the new class in your HTML file more like:

```
<div id="speedometer" class="d-inline-block">
  <span class="barometer d-inline-block dimension"></span>
  <span class="needle ten d-inline-block dimension"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#speedometer {
  position: relative;
}

.d-inline-block{
  display: inline-block;
}

.dimension{
  width: 200px;
  height: 110px;
}

#speedometer .barometer {
  background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp- 
  content/uploads/2019/03/barometer.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#speedometer .needle {
  background-image: url("https://www.turbotobias.dk/wp- 
  content/uploads/2019/03/needle.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 999999;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  transform-origin:50% calc(100% - 8px) ;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use multiple selectors like this

```
 #speedometer,
.barometer,
.needle  {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also use CSS variables but first check the compatibility to know the range of browsers that supports it.